# Is all integration that are computable able to be compute by the substitution method and/or integration by parts method?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Is all single-variable integration that are computable by mathematician theoretically able to be compute by the substitution method and/or integration by parts method?

If not, does that mean much work have to been done additionally by the mathematician in the future?

Comment: The result [$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) is one that cannot be achieved by finding an antiderivative (since $e^{-x^2}$ has no elementary antiderivative), so it certainly can't be found by substitution or integration by parts.  There are many such definite integrals that may be found without computing an antiderivative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every antiderivative that can be expressed in closed form can (in a somewhat trivial sense) be obtained by substitution. If $\int f(x)\,dx=F(x)+C$, then the substitution $u=F(x), du=F'(x)\,dx=f(x)\,dx$ does the trick.